# Remove recursion void function

Tags: c, recursion, void

someone can help me to remove the recursion of this void function ? It doesn't work in some situations. I have tried but I can't get.Thanks. Source: http://www2.dcc.ufmg.br/livros/algoritmos/implementacoes-07.php

```
void ImprimeCaminho(TipoValorVertice Origem, TipoValorVertice v, 
            TipoGrafo *Grafo, int * Dist, TipoCor *Cor,  
            int *Antecessor)
{ if (Origem == v) { printf("%d ", Origem); return; }
  if (Antecessor[v] == -1)
  printf("Nao existe caminho de %d ate %d", Origem, v);
  else { ImprimeCaminho(Origem,Antecessor[v], 
                        Grafo, Dist, Cor, Antecessor);
         printf("%d ", v);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you've shown requires a stack of some kind, which you can implement using an array.  This is an example using a fixed-size array, with an `assert()` that it never overflows - this is roughly equivalent to the original recursive algorithm, since there is in inherently no error-checking for recursing too far either, but you can obviously replace that with some more robust error handling (or even dynamic allocation with resizing).

```
void ImprimeCaminho(TipoValorVertice Origem, TipoValorVertice v, 
            TipoGrafo *Grafo, int * Dist, TipoCor *Cor,  
            int *Antecessor)
{
    int Vertices[MAX_VERTEX];
    int n = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        if (Origem == v)
        {
            printf("%d ", Origem);
            break;
        }

        if (Antecessor[v] == -1)
        {
            printf("Nao existe caminho de %d ate %d", Origem, v);
            break;
        }

        assert(n < sizeof Vertices);
        Vertices[n++] = v;
    }

    while (n > 0)
        printf("%d ", Vertices[--n]);
}
```